# mysql: select the last 10 messages and for each message the last 3 replies

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group

For simplicity lets strip down the messages table to its minimum, with some sample data

```
message_id  reply_to    createdate
1           0           123
2           0           124
3           0           123
4           1           154
5           1           165
```

the reply_to is the message_id wich the message is a reply to

so im looking for a sql-statement/procedure/function/other table design that lets me select the last 10 messages and for each of those the last 3 replies, i dont mind changing the table structure or even keeping some sort of a record for the last 3 replies

just selecting the last 10 messages is

```
SELECT * FROM message ORDER BY createdate LIMIT 10;
```

and for each of those messages the replies are

```
SELECT * FROM message WHERE reply_to = :message_id: ORDER BY createdate LIMIT 3;
```

my attempts so far are:

- a triple outer join over the message table as replies
- a plain join but mysql doesnt allow limits in joins
- useing HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT reply_to) <= 3, but ofcourse HAVING is evaluated last

i couldnt get either of those working

my last option atm is to have a separate table to track the last 3 replies per message

`message_reply:
message_id, r_1, r_2, r_3`

and then updateing that table useing triggers
so a new row in the message table wich is a reply updates the message_reply table

`UPDATE message_reply SET r_3 = r_2, r_2 = r_1, r_1 = NEW.reply_to WHERE message_id = NEW.message_id`

then i could just query the message table for those records

anyone have a better suggestion or even a working SQL statement?

thanks

**EDIT:**

added EXPLAIN results

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY     <derived4>  ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    3    
1   PRIMARY     <derived2>  ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    10  Using where; Using join buffer
1   PRIMARY     r   eq_ref  PRIMARY,message_id,message_id_2     PRIMARY     4   func    1    
4   DERIVED     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    No tables used
5   UNION   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    No tables used
6   UNION   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    No tables used
NULL    UNION RESULT    <union4,5,6>    ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL     
2   DERIVED     m   ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    299727   
3   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  r   ref     reply_to,reply_to_2     reply_to_2  4   testv4.m.message_id     29973
```

**EDIT 2:**

Well i tried the message_reply table method also this is what i did

build the table:

```
message_reply: message_id, r_1, r_2, r_3
```

build the trigger:

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE TRIGGER i_message AFTER INSERT ON message
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF NEW.reply_to THEN
        INSERT INTO message_replies (message_id, r_1) VALUES (NEW.reply_to, NEW.message_id)
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE r_3 = r_2, r_2 = r_1, r_1 = NEW.message_id;
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO message_replies (message_id) VALUES (NEW.message_id);
    END IF;
  END;
|
DELIMITER ;
```

and select the messages:

```
SELECT m.*,r1.*,r2.*,r3.* FROM message_replies mr
LEFT JOIN message m ON m.message_id = mr.message_id
LEFT JOIN message r1 ON r1.message_id = mr.r_1
LEFT JOIN message r2 ON r2.message_id = mr.r_2
LEFT JOIN message r3 ON r3.message_id = mr.r_3
```

Ofcourse with the trigger preprocessing it for me this is the fastest way.

tested with a few more sets of 100k inserts to see the performance hit for the trigger
it took a .4 sec longer to process the 100k rows as it did without the tirgger
total time to insert was about 12 sec (on myIsam tables)

Comment: Check the pairing of mysql and "greatest-n-per-group" tags -- the request is very common.

Comment: @OMG except with a limit 10 on the outer query, there is a better way to do this than a generic greatest-n-per-group which requires numbering every single row in every single lead record

Comment: @Richard aka cyberkiwi: It's a catch-all tag -- the limit on the outside is arbitrary.

Comment: @OMG the tag is, but when a (small) limit is applied to the outer query, there is a better way then the generic form so it is worthy of its own question

Comment: i actually looked at those and clicked trough the first 10 pages but couldnt find any exapmples with the inner limit of 3

Comment: @Paul I can write you one, but it would involve double-row-numbering all records (outer rownum, inner rownum) and would scan the full 10m records.

Comment: @Paul Scheltema: I vote to close when I see nonsense like "it doesn't limit by three", because the number is arbitrary.  3, 5, 10... makes no difference.

Comment: @Richard aka cyberkiwi: I'm not going to get dragged into an argument that based on [pedantry](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pedantry).  You're free to create your own tag about the sub class of greatest-n-per-group, and retag as you need.  It's hard enough to tell people that their question is not a unique snowflake...

Comment: @OMG If you spend just a couple of minutes looking at the MySQL code I have provided, it can clearly work very efficiently when compared to the generic `greatest-n-per-group` solutions. `I'm not arguing against the tag`, I'm just not agreeing with the first comment (that it is common; or that the common solution to g-n-p-g will solve this efficiently).

Comment: @Richard aka cyberkiwi: Then visit the questions and **courteously** inform if not answer.

Comment: @OMG see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095495/mysql-select-the-last-10-messages-and-for-each-message-the-last-3-replies/5096308#5096308

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A working example:

#### EDIT - (see revision for earlier query)

Full table creation and explain plan
*Note: The table "datetable" just contains all dates for about 10 years.  It is used just to generate rows.*

```
drop table if exists messages;
create table messages (
   message_id int primary key, reply_to int, createdate datetime, index(reply_to));

insert into messages 
select @n:=@n+1, floor((100000 - @n) / 10), a.thedate
from (select @n:=0) n
cross join datetable a
cross join datetable b
limit 1000000;
```

The above generates 1m messages, and some valid replies.  The query:

```
select m1.message_id, m1.reply_to, m1.createdate, N.N, r.*
from
(
    select m.*, (
         select group_concat(r.message_id order by createdate)
          from messages r
        where r.reply_to = m.message_id) replies
     from messages m
     order by m.message_id
    limit 10
) m1
inner join ( # this union-all query controls how many replies per message
    select 1 N union all
     select 2 union all
     select 3) N
  on (m1.replies is null and N=1) or (N <= length(m1.replies)-length(replace(m1.replies,',','')))
left join messages r
  on r.message_id = substring_index(substring_index(m1.replies, ',', N), ',', -1)
```

**Time: 0.078 sec**

Explain plan

```
id     select_type         table        type      possible_keys    key      key_len ref                rows    Extra
1      PRIMARY             <derived4>   ALL      (NULL)            (NULL)   (NULL)  (NULL)             3    
1      PRIMARY             <derived2>   ALL      (NULL)            (NULL)   (NULL)  (NULL)             10      Using where
1      PRIMARY             r            eq_ref   PRIMARY           PRIMARY  4       func               1    
4      DERIVED             (NULL)       (NULL)   (NULL)            (NULL)   (NULL)  (NULL)             (NULL)  No tables used
5      UNION               (NULL)       (NULL)   (NULL)            (NULL)   (NULL)  (NULL)             (NULL)  No tables used
6      UNION               (NULL)       (NULL)   (NULL)            (NULL)   (NULL)  (NULL)             (NULL)  No tables used
(NULL) UNION RESULT        <union4,5,6> ALL      (NULL)            (NULL)   (NULL)  (NULL)             (NULL)    
2      DERIVED             m            index    (NULL)            PRIMARY  4       (NULL)             1000301    
3      DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  r            ref      reply_to          reply_to 5       test.m.message_id  5       Using where
```

Comment: thanks, ill try tweaking this a bit, the current version can never use indexes wich is ok for the sample data, but not for 10m records

Comment: @Richard i used explain on the sql and its really nice, but i saw the inner table m selecting all rows in the testset without useing index, i got to go now, im back in an hour, thanks so far :)

Comment: @Paul - that's because there is no order to it, put a specific ORDER (aided by index) and it should take only 10 from `messages m`. Even without an ORDER by, what explain is telling you is that it is using a key with 10m rows, but the actual execution will skip after 10.

Comment: i just created 299.727 rows for my test set and the query allready runs at about 3 sec now on my local machine. i updated my post with the results from explain. it tells me it cannot use a key for table m, probably because of the dependant subquery, and it also selects one 10th of the total rows for the r table

Comment: @Richard forgot to add your name to notify you

Comment: @Paul can you recheck your query and indexes? See edited answer

Comment: @Paul - actually, how many replies are you expecting per message on average?

Comment: @Richard i tested a bit and i finally noticed that the reply length is the determiting factor in the query speed, on inserting the test data i used a randomizer function to generate some reply_to id's but it seems i created to much replies for the selected messages

Comment: @Richard im expecting about 2 to 3 replies per message on average, with most 0 and some in the 20's

Comment: @Richard thank you for your time, im content with the sql for what it is now :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you build your extra table, and make it work with as many steps as necessary. Sometimes to visualize the answer you need extra steps. At the end, you can compile the SQL into one nested statement.

Comment: well did that now, sql runs at 11ms for the meanwhile 500k records in the test set, updated my post to explain to others how i did it

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** This answer provides useful information for comparison for OMG's comments, so even if it needs to be deleted, please leave it up for a while.

> OMG: Check the pairing of mysql and "greatest-n-per-group" tags -- the request is very common.
>   OMG: Then visit the questions and courteously inform if not answer.

I followed your instructions OMG, and this is what I came up with from
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group+mysql

1. [SQL - Give me 3 hits for each type only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775820/sql-give-me-3-hits-for-each-type-only)
2. [mySQL Returning the top 5 of each category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729406/mysql-returning-the-top-5-of-each-category)
3. [MySQL SELECT n records base on GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688664/mysql-select-n-records-base-on-group-by)

You may have misunderstood the question because of the 3 that looked most similar form the first page of results (2 of which are my answers), the questions deal with a single dimension (top n per category) for the entire table.  The solutions offered invariably row_number **ALL** records in the table ordered by category.

Compare that to the optimized answer provided for this question for the problem domain **`top-n-category -> top-m-per-category`** and you will realize that this question is a different one.

There is no need to `visit the questions and courteously inform if not answer` because

1. The answer to those questions are valid
2. The answer to this question is valid