# Select parent and its children with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I will start with the end: I want to get JSON that looks like this:

```
"Message": "Hello World",
"Comments": [
            {
               "text": "Comment 1",
            },
            {
               "text": "Comment 2"
            }
         ],
```

To get the JSON i will take the results as "messages" and call this function on it.

```
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer oSerializer =
new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
string sJSON = oSerializer.Serialize(messages);
```

What I want to know is HOW to get the data from the DB like that so the `Comments` are in a sub-collection, like you can see in the JSON above.

I have 2 tables, the first table holds the messages and the other one holds the comments.
Each comment in comments table has a foreign key with the `messageID`.

Currently, I'm doing this with 2 SQL queries - one for the messages and the second for each message - I just call `GetCommentByID` query. These 2 SQL queries are wasteful since its complexity is O(N^2).

I wonder if I can achieve this by a single SQL query.

I'm just not sure that SQL Server is able to return a sub-dataset or an array.

I also read this question here:
[mysql: select the last 10 messages and for each message the last 3 replies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095495/mysql-select-the-last-10-messages-and-for-each-message-the-last-3-replies)

and it seems that the only way to do it is to get one dataset with all the messages and comments together and then manipulate it on the server.

this is the schema of my tables:

**Messages:**

```
ID, Description
```

**Comments:**

```
ID, MessageID, Body
```

Can I achieve this with single SQL query?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is O(n^2) about this operation - the operation is going to use index seeks which will be O(log n) on table-size of n in worst case, and you will get 10 rows for that and then another 10 similar seeks for the comments - yes, it is m + 1 queries if you have 1 set for the m messages and m more for each message's comments.

But anyway, you asked to do it in one operation.  I'm not sure where the JSON comes in, so I went ahead and simply returned the full JSON of what you wanted as a single column in a single row.

1. This JSON is not necessarily well-escaped
2. You can always just join the two tables (single query) and process the set procedurally, breaking when the Message.ID changes (since there is no builtin JSON library in SQL Server, I kind of assumed you would do this anyway).  The only waste here is that all the Message data is repeated on each row unnecessarily across the wire.

[Link to a Runnable example](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/63234/http-stackoverflow-com-questions-9577122-select-parent-and-its-children-with-sq)

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @Messages AS TABLE (ID INT NOT NULL, Description VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL);
DECLARE @Comments AS TABLE (ID INT NOT NULL, MessageID INT NOT NULL, Body VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO @Messages
VALUES (1, 'Message 1'),
(2, 'Message 2'),
(3, 'Message 3'),
(4, 'Message 4'),
(5, 'Message 5'),
(6, 'Message 6'),
(7, 'Message 7'),
(8, 'Message 8'),
(9, 'Message 9'),
(10, 'Message 10'),
(11, 'Message 11'),
(12, 'Message 12'),
(13, 'Message 13');

INSERT INTO @Comments
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY msg.ID, Numbers.num)
, msg.ID
, msg.Description + ':Commment ' + CONVERT(varchar(max), Numbers.num)
FROM @Messages msg
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 AS num UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5) AS Numbers;

-- SELECT * FROM @Messages;
-- SELECT * FROM @Comments;

SELECT '[ ' + STUFF(Z.Messages, 1, 2, '') + ' ] ' AS JSON
FROM (
SELECT ', ' + MessageWComments FROM (
SELECT TOP 10 '{ "Message": "' + msg.Description + '", "Comments": [ ' + STUFF(X.Comments, 1, 2, '') + ' ] }' AS MessageWComments
FROM @Messages msg
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 3 ', { "text" : "' + Body + '" }'
    FROM @Comments cmt
    WHERE MessageID = msg.ID
    ORDER BY cmt.ID DESC
    FOR XML PATH ('')
    ) AS X (Comments)
ORDER BY msg.ID DESC
) AS Y (MessageWComments)
FOR XML PATH ('')) AS Z(Messages)
```

Comment: thanks. i will get JSON by c# code. that not the important part.
i just wanted to get the combined data in sub-dataset

Answer (score 0):

A delimited concatenation of Comment strings by message may be the way to go (SQL Server 2005 or higher).

```
select distinct
[Message]=m.[Description]
, Comments=(STUFF((SELECT ',' + c1.Body FROM Comments c1 WHERE  c.MessageID = c1.MessageID ORDER BY c.ID
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT).value('root[1]','nvarchar(max)'),1,1,''))
from [Messages] m
inner join Comments c on c.MessageID=m.ID;
```

Per your previous comment, I am leaving out the C# formatting and just returning the basic aggregates.